# Slime mode error

Tags: emacs, clojure, read-eval-print-loop, slime, elpa

I was following the guide and information from [A gentle tutorial to Emacs/Swank/Paredit for Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285437/a-gentle-tutorial-to-emacs-swank-paredit-for-clojure)

However after opening elpa and installing clojure-mode, slime and paredit. I restarted emacs and then attempted to use M-x slime however it continually says no match . What am I doing wrong?

I then tried to install clojure-mode from marmalade http://marmalade-repo.org/packages I byte-compiled package el and then added 
    (add-to-list 'package-archives '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")) to my.emacs. However marmalade errors with 
    Symbol's value as variable is void: package-archives .

Unsure exactly what I am doing wrong I am on windows7 using emacs 23.3. I have clojure installed to c:/clojure.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My init.el has both `(require 'package)` and `(package-initialize)`. It's not very big, it looks like this:

```
(require 'package)
;; Add the original Emacs Lisp Package Archive
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("elpa" . "http://tromey.com/elpa/"))
;; Add the user-contributed repository
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)
```

I'm on emacs 24 ([a development build](http://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/emacs-20110613-bin-i386.zip)) on Windows 7. I had trouble getting emacs 23 to work with packages too, it was easier for me to just upgrade.

By the way, I noticed that if I set a HOME environment variable, emacs looks there for the .emacs.d directory (instead of in %USER_PROFILE%\AppData\Roaming).

Answer (score 2):

1. Download package.el (don't follow the instructions on the ELPA site, just download the package.el provided on marmalade's site).
2. Put package.el in your .emacs.d directory (~/.emacs.d/).
3. Add the following to your .emacs file (~/.emacs):

---

```
;;Load path to my packages

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/")

;;Load ELPA (the package.el you downloaded from marmalade)

(require 'package)

;;Load Marmalade (the code found on marmalade's welcome page)

(add-to-list 'package-archives '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
```

That's it! I really hope this helps.

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to mention that you need to add (package-initialize) at the end of the code I provided. If you don't add this line, the packages will install, but won't load.

Answer (score 1):

I think, that you need to put

```
(require 'package)
```

before 'add-to-list'

P.S. and add following call after 'add-to-list'

```
(package-initialize)
```

this command will load installed packages and activate them

P.P.S. '(require 'package)' maybe not needed, but I'm personally not using 'package.el'

Comment: Thanks it currently still wont work. ELPA works but marmalade wont. Which is a shame because clojure mode on marmalade is 1.9.4 and on ELPA 1.7.1. One things certain the directions on http://marmalade-repo.org/ are definitely vague and likely not accurate.

Comment: If you always want to have fresh version, you can look onto el-get package (https://github.com/dimitri/el-get)

Comment: I just tried on my fresh Emacs (from BZR) and package.el shows version from marmalade-repo -- 1.9.2

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you're missing either **(require 'package)** or **(package-initialize)**. You can check out my setup [here](https://github.com/bbatsov/emacs-dev-kit) - I'm using both marmalade and clojure-mode on Windows 7 and it works like a charm.

Comment: I have put the package.el in my .emacs.d directory and it still wont load with the (require 'package) and/or (package-initialize) in .emacs. I tried your git package created a directory and cloned to C:\emacs_kit\emacs-dev-kit created ln -s C:/emacs_kit/emacs-dev-kit ~/.emacs.d . After starting emacs though M-X slime still had no match error.

Comment: On windows 7 .emacs.d should be in "c:/Users/Username/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d" - otherwise Emacs won't pick it up.

Comment: oh yeah I agree, I am trying to setup emacs to work with clojure on a XP PC, Win7 Laptop & Vectorlinux box.

Comment: `~/.emacs.d` is not on the load-path by default, so even if you've put `package.el` there, you won't be able to require it. Try `(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d"))`

Answer (score 0):

Do not know it is same problem, I faced when I were trying to use quicklisp's swank/slime

Finally I found that few /contrib/*.el  packages were dependent on each other
if A's dependency package is B, if B is not byte-compiled than A will not compile

when you do
(require 'A)

it will throw
  Symbol's variable value is void: A

So ensure you compile each package than try require.