# Setting up Uber development mode in Emacs for Clojure

Tags: emacs, clojure, slime, swank

I am aware of

[A gentle tutorial to Emacs/Swank/Paredit for Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285437/a-gentle-tutorial-to-emacs-swank-paredit-for-clojure)

I basically have the same question.

I noted that there is an EDIT saying that the instructions are outdated, and there will be an update (I don't see where the update is posted.)

Thus, my question:

What is the "right way" to setup Emacs w/ Clojure?

Context: I've been coding Clojure w/ VIM for the past few years; but Slime/Swank looks quite impressive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://dev.clojure.org/display/doc/Getting+Started+with+Emacs or more directly, https://github.com/technomancy/clojure-mode/blob/master/README.md, for a pretty good overview of what you need to set up. Basically, install clojure-mode and the leiningen plugin for swank-clojure and you're pretty much good to go. Once those are installed, you just create a new leiningen project, open a clj file from within the project somewhere, and do a `M-x clojure-jack-in`.

Comment: Is leon install swank-clojure supposed to end up pulling clojure 1.2.1? That part confused me [and made me believe those instructions were out of date.]

Comment: Yeah, I think it still does. Leiningen uses clojure 1.2 internally. It works fine with projects using 1.3 -- it just uses 1.2 to run the build tasks.