# reloading a ns in repl

Tags: emacs, clojure

Lets say I have a code file that has the ns - (ns abc.a). Now I start my repl and am in the ns- (use-ns 'abc.a).

Now if I change any code in the file, how do I get to reload the ns in the repl?

Thanks,
Murtaza

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can hot reload the code with `(require :reload 'abc.a)` or `(require :reload-all 'abc.a)`. The latter also reloads all the required namespaces of `abc.a` while the former only reloads `abc.a`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`load-file`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/load-file) to reload the file.

Comment: Interestingly, load-file does not set my name space in the [lien] REPL (Ubuntu 10.04). By that I mean, if I start out lein repl, ns is user, but if I load my file using (load-file src/xml_lib/core.clj) the ns does not change. I have to issue (ns xml_lib.core).

Answer (score 2):

When you set a namespace in REPL you don't load any code from the file where the namespace is defined. You need to execude all the code from the file (simplest way is copy-paste).

So if your file looks like this:

```
(ns abc.a)
(def x 3)
```

then after executing `user=>(ns abc.a)` in REPL you get the prompt `abc.a=>`. Your namespace is changed but there is nothing in it yet. Type `x` to see it is not defined. It is only after executing `abc.a=>(def x 3)`, that you get your code loaded to the ns in REPL.

If you then change your `x` definition in file (say to `(def x 5)`), just type the new one in REPL to get this code reloaded.

If you're using emacs, I'd advise you to read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285437/a-gentle-tutorial-to-emacs-swank-paredit-for-clojure).

Comment: After you configure emacs+slime it is enough to hit `C-x C-e` to get the code you've just written reloaded. I don't think people feel the need for anything quicker that this, so I wouldn't expect any automatic code-from-file-reloading-tools. However, if you want one - keep looking.

Answer (score 2):

when using emacs and slime you can hit ctrl-c ctrl-l  to  **reload the currend namespace and reload anything it includes.**